# template is not loading in magento custom module

Tags: magento, module

i am customizing magento module for frontend, I have add a page but this page is not showing content, advice me where i a wrong. bellow are my code :

```
class Gaboli_Warehouse_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

Block -

```
class Gaboli_Warehouse_Block_Location_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{

   public function __construct()
   {
      parent::__construct();
   }
}
```

Layout xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout  version="0.1.0">

   <warehouse_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="warehouse/location_list" name="warehouse_location" template="gaboli/warehouses.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </warehouse_index_index>

</layout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether the execution reaches to your template file. 
Execute 
 `die('here');` statement in your template file and see whether it gets there or not. If not there may be problem in the template path you asssign here.

```
<block type="warehouse/location_list" name="warehouse_location" template="gaboli/warehouses.phtml" />
```

Other codes seems fine.

Reply where you get into this.

Hope this will help.

Comment: path is correct.... if i am changing in layout xml there is no effect on page. I am able to track controller but not block.

Comment: In layout xml default reference is working but "warehouse_index_index" not working

Comment: Now it is working, i changed handler "warehouse_index_index" to "gaboli_warehouse_index_index"